# Remove Unwanted CSS Styling from DataTables Scroller

Tags: css, datatables

I am using bootstrap to have shading when the mouse hovers over a table row.  But when I introduce scrolling into the picture, all the even rows are set to `background-color: white`.  These are over riding the bootstrap rules.

So the first thing I did was to check what order I was loading the CSS, assuming that *cascading* style sheets were subject to the order they are loaded, with later ones overwriting previous rules.

```
<link href="/DataTables/datatables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```

This didn't change anything.  The datatables rule is still overriding bootstrap.

I then tried adding a rule inline:

```
<style>
  div.DTS tbody tr.even:hover {
    background-color: inherit;
  }
</style>
```

but this just inherits DataTable's rule.  Changing color to transparent likewise fails.

So, I'm left with two different hacks that will work, but neither of them is (IMO) a good way to do it.

1. I can overwrite the rule overwriting bootstrap, trusting that bootstrap will never change the hover color:

   ```
   /* overwrite the overwriting of bootstrap hover shading. */
   div.DTS tbody tr.even:hover {
       background-color: #f5f5f5;
   }
   ```
2. Simply comment out the offending rule in `datatables.css`, and have it break if/when I next upgrade DataTables:

   ```
   /*
   div.DTS tbody tr.even {
     background-color: white;
   }
   */
   ```

Is there a more flexible way to undo the "helpful" stylings that I don't want?

Comment: _"assuming that cascading style sheets were subject to the order they are loaded"_ - that's not what cascading means. Order is the lowest part of determining _specificity_, and that is what you want to go read up on regarding this.

Comment: Also you usually have to use `!important` to override bootstrap rules.

Comment: @CBroe Now that you point that out, yeah, I completely missed the boat on cascading.  Thanks for putting a name to the part I wasn't seeing.